# Does moving out of multiple squares that a single opponent threatens provoke multiple attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, opportunity-attack

In the [Core Rulebook FAQ regarding tiny creatures moving into creatures' spaces](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9u95) it casually mentions that:

> moving out of multiple of a creature’s threatened squares in the same move action doesn’t provoke two attacks of opportunity.

However, when I checked the rest of the FAQ and the [Attack of Opportunity rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) I couldn't find anything that confirmed or denied this.
Does moving out of multiple threatened squares in the same action provoke multiple attacks of opportunity?

Comment: I actually like your version of the question over the previous iteration, much cleaner, but ultimately we already have the answers you’re looking for.

Comment: I don't normally upvote a question closed as a duplicate, but this is *so much clearer* than the question it's duplicating, it deserves it. Folks with the same question will find this one much more easily than they'll find the original.

Comment: I would even say that the other question is different, more in relation to the feat they're asking about. Whether or not it's different *enough* is above my pay grade.